# Is webview compulsory for OAuth2 on official iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, oauth-2.0

A friend and I have been working on a website.
He has developed the full website and plugged an OAuth2 system into it.

I am currently building the official iOS app and I was wondering about the login process. Is it compulsory to go through the webview given the fact that it is not an app from an external developer? In other terms, can I simply make queries through the app to get any token I would need?

I fear about the UX of the app if everything has to go through the webview.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. WebView is typically used when integrating with 3rd party apps that don't expose a login API and only implement OAuth2 flows.

You can simply login users if you control the APIs (like native Facebook would do). If you want to stay "standards compliant", consider using the "Resource Owner" flow. The "shape" of this API is quite simple. Looks like this: https://auth0.com/docs/auth-api#!#post--oauth-ro

(look at the API payload/data, not at the actual implementation of this particular service)

Comment: Looks like that documentation has moved to: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#resource-owner